# Google colab + drive 'rate limit exceeded'

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I was using google colab with drive for saving model and notebooks, when colab return error, that he can't autosave notebook. I skip this moment and some times later I found that notebook can't save model. I tried find information about 'rate limit exceeded' error, which returns when I try save notebook. Google return me information about google api, but I'm not manually using api, mb only colab using drive api. How I can fix it?

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe? Are you using Drive files in Colab via the filesystem, or trying to save the notebook itself?

Comment: This notebook I try save on drive(becouse he on the drive). Model I try save on Drive too. I can upload notebook but he haven't information about error + before I can save this notebook